# SOLR full-import not working

Tags: apache, solr, solrj, solr4

I have the problem with full-import. if I did the full import also the all documents are not taking the updated data from the database view.

kindly find the steps below for more information.

1. I have updated the database view i.e changed the table name for the single column in the view.
2. did the full import
3. But still some of the documents have the old data(for updated single field).
4. And the document get changed only if the document have changes.

example.

i have the field name as "hits". now i have taken the "hits" from different table than previous so that i did the full import to change the "hits value" in all the document in the solr. But some documents still have the old hits value. even i have restarted also the problem not get solved.

kindly check and help me.

Comment: Are you doing a commit after the full-import?

Comment: yes am doing clean and commit

Comment: Is reindex helps to resolve the problem.?

Comment: Hm, the behavior sounds a lot more like a delta-import than a full-import. Can you edit the question with your data-config.xml and the relevant part of your schema.xml?